# Composer-"bug" in shopware project

Tags: php, shopware6

I have problems with the composer in my shopware-project.
After a composer install or composer update I got following error:

```
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
- Required package "shopware/core" is not present in the lock file.
- Required (in require-dev) package "phpunit/phpunit" is in the lock file as "9.5.2" but that does not satisfy your constraint "~9.5.17".
This usually happens when composer files are incorrectly merged or the composer.json file is manually edited.
Read more about correctly resolving merge conflicts https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts.md
and prefer using the "require" command over editing the composer.json file directly https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require-r
Script @composer install --working-dir vendor/shopware/recovery --no-interaction --no-scripts handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 4
```

deleting the composer.lock did'nt help. Anybody an idea what's going on?

"composer update" -> should work without an error

Comment: Remove the lock file and the vendor directory and run `composer install`.

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json` file contents? Do you get exactly the same output after you deleted the `composer.lock` file or a different error? Does `composer install --no-scripts` work?

Answer (score 4):

For me it was workaround with changing composer version from newest to a bit older `composer self-update 2.4.4` as suggested by **DevertNet** (article: https://github.com/shopware/production/issues/168). But answer by **shyim** explains in details how to fix problem at it source (solution underneath).

1. Update composer.json file (remove lines with "-")

```
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "[ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "[ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
-           "@composer install --working-dir vendor/shopware/recovery --no-interaction --no-scripts",
-           "@composer install --working-dir=vendor/shopware/recovery/Common --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest",
            "[ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:finish"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
-           "@composer install --working-dir vendor/shopware/recovery --no-interaction --no-scripts",
-           "@composer install --working-dir=vendor/shopware/recovery/Common --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest",
            "[ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:finish"
        ]
    }
```

```
   "require": {
        "php": "^7.4.3 || ^8.0",
        "composer-runtime-api": "^2.0",
        "shopware/administration": "~v6.4.0",
        "shopware/core": "~v6.4.0",
        "shopware/elasticsearch": "~v6.4.0",
-       "shopware/recovery": "~v6.4.0",
        "shopware/storefront": "~v6.4.0"
    },
```

2. Update to Flex Template
   - The Flex template does not contain the Recovery anymore. https://www.shopware.com/en/news/shopware-goes-symfony-flex/
3. Run composer update inside that folder

- By calling update, you generate a newer lock file and then finally can run it.
  `composer update -d vendor/shopware/recovery/Common/`